# Sugar Orm multiple access issue

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

I am using `Sugar ORM` in my application.

There are *insertion* and *deletion* in almost every server call of each activity.

I am getting `IllegalStateException` when I switch the activities or fragments.

The reason behind this exception is: I am performing multiple `save()` or `read()` operations at the same time.

I am working to avoid multiple accesses at same time to avoid this issue, but not getting any success.

Please suggest me a good approach to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the 1.3 beta version. That fixed it for me.

https://github.com/satyan/sugar/tree/master/dist